# Unable to increase the java heap size

Tags: java

I'm using 64bit Ubuntu and java vm 64 bit version.

I have 8GB ram.

I am unable to change the java heap size to 4096m, not even 2048m.

I tried these things:

```
uname -i
```

Output:

> x86_64

```
java -version
```

OUTPUT:

> openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

When I tried to change the heap size:

```
java -Xmx:4096m
```

OUTPUT

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx:4096m
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

**The same for 2048m size**

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

OUTPUT:

```
size_t ErgoHeapSizeLimit                        = 0                                         {product} {default}
size_t HeapSizePerGCThread                      = 43620760                                  {product} {default}
size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 130023424                                 {product} {ergonomic}
size_t LargePageHeapSizeThreshold               = 134217728                                 {product} {default}
size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 2067791872                                {product} {ergonomic}
uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5835340                                {pd <p>product} {ergonomic}
uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122911450                              {pd <p>product} {ergonomic}
uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122911450                              {pd <p>product} {ergonomic}
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

First check the default value:

```
java -XshowSettings:vm
```

then you'll need to edit the settings file for the JVM:
    `sudo vim /etc/profile`
Add this to the beginning of the file:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx(size you want in here)m
```

Press ESC, type `:wq` and press Enter

After that you can execute the same command to check if the size was changed:

```
java -XshowSettings:vm
```

Comment: First I tried to edit that file /etc/profile but I can't. That file is read only. Then I simply typed the command that you have mentioned in terminal. It finally works!

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: also if the file was read only you can also change it with the chmod command